# Stored procedure executes successfully but changes are not saved to database

Tags: c#, wcf, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following stored procedure that I invoke through a WCF service (C#.NET).

The procedure executes successfully (I traced using profile), problem is that changes are not saved to database. I googled a lot but I couldn't find a solution to this problem...

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_create_x]
   (
       @X VarChar(10), @Y VarChar(2), @Z DateTime,
       @A VarChar(10), @B DateTime, @C Int)
   AS
   BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT x FROM tblTable WHERE x = @X)
BEGIN
            INSERT INTO 
                tblTable (x, y, z, a, b, c)
            VALUES (@X, @Y, @Z, @A, @B, @C)     
    END 
END
RETURN @@ERROR
```

The C# code that is used to invoke the sp is as follows:

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_create_x", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@X", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "somevalue";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Y", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "somevalue";                   
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Z", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@A", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "somevalue";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@B", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now; 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@C", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1; 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RETURN", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

    cmd.Transaction = trans;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    int errCode = (int)cmd.Parameters["@RETURN"].Value;
    conn.Close();

    if (errCode != 0)
    {
       throw new Exception(string.Format("Error!));
    }
```

What am I missing???

Thanks a billion in advance

Comment: when is the `cmd.Transaction = trans;` transaction commited?

Comment: OMG, Thanks a lot, sometimes one gets blind!!!   Thanks for opening my eyes, how can I mark your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing the `cmd.Transaction = trans` assigns a transaction that is never comitted.